# Display UART in HTML (web site)

Tags: javascript, php, html, uart

I receive continuously data by uart sérial port. 
How can i print this data on my html web site and update it dynamically ?
I use a raspberry pi 3 with apache server.
I can use php, javascript, python... and many languages.

Comment: As it stands this is going to be too broad for SO's QA format... could you refine the question down to what you've tried and where you're stuck?

Comment: Create a database table to store the incoming data from the UART. Use it like a buffer for the incoming data, then the front end can grab data in chunks from the database by long poling from a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a NodeJS server, with `express` for example.
Then use the [`serialport`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) npm module to get data from your serial port.
Then send this data through a websocket, create a web page, and use the [Websocket Javascript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) to retrieve the data from your websocket.

This way, you can display real-time data from serial port on your website. I've used this 'stack' to build a connected aquaponics system in a Hackathon and it worked well !

It would even be simplier if you use [socket.io](https://socket.io), since it provides simple library and code example for both the back-end and the front-end part.

Hope it helps,
Best regards